# How to make Unity icons enlarge on mouse over as with Cairo Dock?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, tweak

I have the Cairo dock installed and I love it.  When I mouseover the icons, they enlarge, gain focus, etc.  Is there a way to make the icons on the Unity sidebar behave in that same manner?  I have installed Ubuntu Tweak, Unity Tweak, and even Compiz.  Between those applications, I would think I could achieve my goal but I can't.  Is there a setting somewhere I am missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the way Unity's launcher (which is not a dock according to Canonical) works, you can't do this.

You can however create a setup where Cairo Dock is aligned to the left of your screen as the launcher would be (as a compromise).

Comment: Thank you, RolandiXor.  I will experiment further with Cairo.

Comment: @vivid_vibe if this answers your question, you can (though you don't have to) mark it as answered using the tick next to the question.